# What is the load that nodejs could handle

Tags: javascript, performance, optimization, node.js, nowjs-sockets

I'm building an app with nodejs, that makes live sync with all clients that connect to the server. I use nowjs to make my code part easier.

I'm planning it to host this app in an event, say 2000 participants. Will node be able to handle the app running on a server - Core2Duo, 4G ram, 2M l2 cache, if all the participants are using this app simultaneously....

Server uptime - roughly 5 days

Also what is the maximum load that it can take. What will happen if 10000 users simultaneously hit the server?. (Note: Live Sync is happeninig for every event the client performs)

Answer (score 5):

This all depends on your application's code, what exactly are you doing in it etc.

There is a nice article where you can read about Theoretical Node.js Real time Performance here: http://blog.3rd-eden.com/post/5809079469/theoretical-node-js-real-time-performance